# Помогите найти ошибку в задаче

Tags: python, python-3.x

Вот задача - Задача Homework. В одном из восьмых классов известной в городе школы учатся три интересных ученика. Конечно, домашнее задание по математике, которое получают они домой одинаковое, но делать дома они его не хотят. Поэтому их классный руководитель решил оставлять Даниила, Аню и Эдуарда после уроков у себя чтобы они делали домашнее задание вместе. Аня меньше чем ее друзья ловила ворон и чесала затылок, и сделала задач в 2 раза больше чем Даниил и Эдуард вместе. Известно, что ребята, чтобы не опередить друг друга, решили одинаковое количество задач по математике каждый. Помогите определить сколько задач по математике выполнил самостоятельно каждый из учеников.Входные данные. Задача Homework читает с устройства стандартного ввода единственное число - общее количество упражнений, которую сделали дети (N <= 1000000).

Исходные данные. Программа выводит на устройство стандартного вывода три целых числа через пробелы - сколько задач сделал Даниил, количество задач, сделала Аня и количество задач, сделал Эдуард.

пример

входные данные
120

Исходные данные

20 80 20

Вот моя програма:

```
    n = int(input())
    r = n // 3
    q = r * 2
    a = q // 2 // 2
    print(a, q, a)
```

Помогите найти ошибку

Результат проверки

- Тест|    Результат|  Время роботи

01  FAILED (Time Out)   0.05 с

02  FAILED (Time Out)   0.04 с

03  FAILED (Time Out)   0.05 с

04  FAILED (Time Out)   0.05 с

05  FAILED (Time Out)   0.05 с

06  FAILED (Time Out)   0.05 с

07  FAILED (Time Out)   0.05 с

08  FAILED (Time Out)   0.05 с

09  FAILED (Time Out)   0.05 с

10  FAILED (Time Out)   0.05 с

Прошло тестов: 0 из 10.

Набрано баллов: 0 из 100.

Comment: Так ошибка в решении или в скорости выполнения/обработке исключений?)

Comment: В том-то и вопрос, Я НЕ ЗНАЮ!

Answer (score 1):

Вы точно правильно переписали условие? Или изложили его в собственном понимании? Потому как ваша задача, так как она сформулирована, не всегда имеет решение. Например, если задано входное число 121, то корректного решения не будет.

Поэтому, как минимум надо писать так:

```
n = int(input())
if n%6==0: 
    m=n // 6
    print (m, m*4, m)
```

или исправлять условие задачи.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема не в решении, а в скорости выполнения.

В вашем решении вы используйте 4 арифметические операции, что скорее всего и приводит к `timeout`. Попробуйте снизить количество операций, например, до 2-х:

```
n = int(input())
m = n // 6
print (m, m*4, m)
```

Comment: Теперь она виполняет 1 правильную проверку из 10

Comment: @Денис Где вы проводите тесты?

Comment: Вот тут -- https://online.netoi.org.ua/cgi-bin/i2004/members4.py